# Git Workflow - remote shared repo AND staging server?

Tags: git, workflow, production-environment, staging, repository

Following the [git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and also read [git staging & production question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844369/git-production-staging-server-workflow).  My remote repo is also used as my staging repo.  It is a BARE repo.

Current Workflow

`Workstations 1,2,3,4   - non-bare, cloned from remote, PUSHes to remote

Remote Repo - bare repo, neither pushes nor pulls, serves as staging repo

Production server - non-bare, PULLs from remote`

Should there be a separate remote repo and staging repo?  If so, which should be bare since they both can't be?